# If I cure myself from vampirism and I don't cure Serana, will I still be able to turn back into a vampire?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm a Vampire Lord but I'm getting pretty tired of being a vampire. If I cure myself but don't cure Serana will I still be able to become Vampire (Vampire Lord) again? Or will that be it of being a vampire?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes.** If you've completed the [Kindred Judgment](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Kindred_Judgment) quest and as long as Serana is not [cured of vampirism](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Serana#Curing_Serana.27s_Vampirism), Serana can turn you into a Vampire Lord. You can repeatedly switch between curing yourself of vampirism through the [Rising at Dawn](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Rising_at_Dawn) quest and asking Serana to turn you back into a Vampire Lord, with no limits.